# How to verify traffic and Google search results when purchasing a domain from a private party?

Tags: seo, domains, traffic

I have my eye on a domain that is for sale. After some research I've determined that traffic is the biggest bargaining chip the owner has. The domain is a 6 character .com and consists of two "keywords", but they combine in a way that not too many would be interested. It sold years ago for 1200 USD and is listed at $3100 now. I'm thinking it's worth more like $500, unless it has an unusual amount of traffic (it's currently hosting a parked "buy this domain" site). How can I find and verify traffic information and Google search results for this domain?

Comment: You can ask to view their traffic stats (e.g., Google Analytics, AWStats, etc...). If it's a parked domain, they're likely using a third-party service, or is itself a domainer. In that case, they may not be able to provide access to stats. There are other clues you can find yourself though:  use the Google search operator `site:example.com` to see how many URLs are indexed, third-party sites to give you an idea of how many _backlinks_ are pointing to it, do a Google search for just "example.com" (in quotes) to see how many mentions there are of it... Keep in mind that unless the traffic  ...

Comment: is relevant to the content you'll be serving, it's not really of much value and will only result in bounces. The value of a domain is really what you think you can make out of it once it's been parked for a while.

Comment: Have you asked the private party for the stats?    This is kind of small potatoes.  For larger purchases due diligence would usually include looking at a Google Analytics account provided by the seller.

Comment: @Stephen I haven't engaged the seller yet. Is the sellers Google account the only way?